# Thymeleaf Template not rendering param value inside th if condition

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using thymeleaf template for my spring boot application. Here below the main page,

```
<div th:replace="content :: content"></div>
```

and inside content fragment,

```
<div th:fragment="content">
   <h4 th:if="${param.val== 'abc'}">SOME-TEXT</h4> // not working
   <h4 th:if="${param.val== 'abc'}" th:text="${param.val}"></h4> // not working
   <h4 th:text="${param.val}"></h4> // working and value is abc
   <h4 th:unless="${param.val== 'abc'}" th:text="${param.val}"></h4> // working - value in html text is abc
<h4 th:unless="${param.val== 'abc'}">SOME-TEXT</h4> // Working, value is SOME-TEXT
</div>

URL: domain/?val=abc
```

I want to display: **SOME-TEXT** in html if param.val == 'abc'.
Value 'abc' is coming inside th:text. But inside th:if failing.

Seems some hidden extra strings added to param.val?
Any suggestion?

Comment: th:if is only responsible deciding whether to include that <h4 /> or not. If you still want "SOME-TEXT" to be replaced with "abc", you need to use th:text as well: `<h4 th:if="${param.val== 'abc'}" th:text="${param.val}">`

Comment: Yes. But somewhat th;if with param.val check is not working. <h4 th:if="${param.val== 'abc'}" th:text="${param.val}"> --> not working. but <h4 th:text="${param.val}"> --> working

Comment: Also, <h4 th:unless="${param.val== 'abc'}" th:text="${param.val}"></h4> --> working. 
Seems some extra characters added in param.val?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Thymeleaf function `${param.val}` will return a request parameter called `val`. But this could be a multivalued object (e.g. an array) - for example consider this (which is a valid construction):

```
?val=abc&val=def
```

So to work with a single-valued string, you can do this:

```
<h4 th:if="${#strings.toString(param.val)} == 'abc'" th:text="'SOME-TEXT-2'">SOME-TEXT-1</h4>
```

This prints `SOME-TEXT-2` in the web page.

Or you can use this:

```
<h4 th:if="${#strings.toString(param.val)} == 'abc'">SOME-TEXT-1</h4>
```

Which prints `SOME-TEXT-1`.

Just out of interest, if you used that first example `val=abc&val=def`, then you can see what happens with this:

```
<h4 th:text="${param.val}"></h4>
```

It prints an array:

```
[abc, def]
```

You may see something like this when processing a series of related checkboxes (just as one example).

**Update:**

For a null-check, using Thymeleaf, you can do this:

```
<h4 th:if="${param.val} != null and 
           ${#strings.toString(param.val)} == 'abc'">SOME-TEXT-2</h4>
```

In this specific case, it isn't really needed, as you are not doing anything with the null value which might cause a problem.

It's more relevant if you are chaining values in objects `foo.bar.baz` - and you need to check if `foo` or `bar` are null to avoid a null pointer exception.

Bear in mind that Spring's expression language has the [safe navigation operator](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-operator-safe-navigation), which can be very helpful in such cases: `foo.?bar.?baz`, allowing you to write more concise null handling than with Thymeleaf alone. But again, not relevant to your specific example from the question.

Comment: ${#strings.toString(param.val)} == 'abc' --> Works. Thank you, saved My Day.
Can you pls include in your answer how to check ${#strings.toString(param.val)} == 'abc' && not == null also? So that it will be complete super answer for me. :)